# C++ Template class function as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, priority-queue, standard-library

What is the right way to implement a class that acts (as far the template part is concerned) like the priority queue of the standard template library, in the sense that I need to create a data structure (parametrized for the type with a normal template, and this part is ok) but with in addition a compare function that I would like to pass as a template parameter.
How to implement that?
Thanks

EDIT: Requested Pseudo code (in comments)

```
template <class T, "syntax for the compare function?">
class myclass
{ 
'I have to refer in some way to the compare function here?'
... }

myclass:: myfunctionusingcomparefunction(){
  if('how to use the compare function here?'){...
}else{...}
}
```

EDIT2: Better explanation

What I was asking is how to implement a class that is able to compare (or apply a function) to elements of a template type.
I was mentioning the priority queue class of the standard template class because it allows to select a template class that overrides the operator() to compare the elements (that is necessary in the ordered insertion):
In the std::priority_list case the second template parameter is the comparator class.

```
priority_list<ObjectType, ObjectComparatorType> myQueue;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) already allows you to specify a comparison function as its third template argument.

Comment: yes, I was only taking it as an example. I want to do a thing like that with my class, in the sense that I want to pass a comparison function to a class and I would know the right syntax and how to handle it @MilesBudnek

Comment: write some pseudo code

Comment: @Daniel Follow the link and copy the prototype from there. Or search your hard drive (or just the compiler installation's headers) for the file named `queue`, and then you can see exactly how it works. Or find the same [online](https://github.com/awong-dev/ndk/blob/master/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc%2B%2B/libcxx/include/queue#L384).

Comment: @Potatoswatter ok thanks I will check now

Comment: When you say you want to compare, do you want to write the compare-code yourself in the function (like a lambda) or do you want to use stuff like less, equal_to, greater and stuff? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/equal_to/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just have a member of your comparison function type and have a constructor that takes a reference to that type so that the object can be passed a function pointer/lambda/`std::function` if needed.  Here's how the GNU libstdc++ does it for `std::priority_queue` (with the irrelevant bits stripped away):

```
template <class _Tp, class _Sequence = vector<_Tp>, 
          class _Compare = less<typename _Sequence::value_type> >
class  priority_queue {
protected:
  _Sequence c;
  _Compare comp;
public:
  explicit priority_queue(const _Compare& __x) :  c(), comp(__x) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, taking into account the example of the priority list a solution for my problem can be the following: my template class takes three template parameters, the type of the priority_queue object, the type of the priority object and a comparator class that must override the operator() to compare priority objects.
An object of the comparator class is given in the comparator class is given in the constructor

priorityQueue.hpp

```
template <class T, class Prio, class Comp>
class priorityQueue{
    template <class T, class Prio>
    class Node{
        T elem;
        Node *next;
        Prio priority;

        public:
        Node(T e, int p) : elem(e), priority(p) {}
    };

    /*class priorityExc{
    public:
        const char* what(){ return "Priority must be in [0, 10]";}
    };*/

    class emptyExc{
    public:
        const char* what(){ return "No element to remove";}
    };


    Node<T, Prio> *head;
    int len;
    Comp comparator; //must overload the operator()

    public:
    priorityQueue(Comp cmp) : comparator(cmp), len(0) {}
    void insert (T myElem, Prio myPriority);// throw (priorityExc);
    T remove() throw (emptyExc);
};
```

Using this approach, an implementation of the insert method, that insert an element in the queue in a priority-order way, could be the following:

```
template <class T, class Prio, class Comp>
void priorityQueue<T, Prio, Comp>::insert(T myElem, Prio myPriority) //throw (priorityExc)
{
    //if(myPriority > 10 || myPriority < 0) throw priorityExc;
    Node<T, Prio> *node = new Node(myElem, myPriority);
    if(head == 0){
        head = node;
        head->next = 0;
    }
    else{
        Node *temp = head, *p = head;
        while(comparator(temp->priority, node->priority) > 0){
            p = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        p->next = node;
        node->next = temp;
    }
}
```